# Searching for a halachic diagram of female anatomy

Tags: product-recommendation, parts-of-the-body, niddah, pictures

I am interested in finding a diagram that depicts female anatomy as it relates to the halachos of *Niddah*.

Preferably, I would like to find two different models - one that displays anatomy as the Talmud seems to have understood it (which is probably not the same as the way we understand it), and one that displays the anatomy as we understand it, with labels matching up to the halachic classifications.

I am aware that both of these diagrams would involve matters that are subject to dispute, both among Rishonim and Acharonim.  My ideal diagram would account for those disputes.

I am looking for an actual diagram, not a chart which does not convey the layout of the actual anatomy (such as Rabbi Forst has in his Laws of Niddah).

<sub>(If you post a diagram here as an image please use 'spoiler format' to post the image, like so: `>! ![alt text][1]`)</sub>

Comment: This has been a while since I have had to learn this. I recall that when I was in yeshiva, there was a pamphlet that I think is called "Pirchei Shoshanim"? IIRC, it had several useful diagrams. I think this pamphlet may still be around or obtainable. This is a good question, as I think I will have to relearn some of these halachot. And, no, I'm not pregnant, though one of my doctors thinks that I am ;-)

Comment: @IsaacMoses the Artscroll gemara?  I have never looked at it.

Comment: @mevaqesh I'm not sure I understand your first option.  And I don't know why you are singling out the Rishonim when it seems to be Tannaim or at least Amoraim.

Comment: IMHO, the best diagram, both from a biological standpoint and Halachic standpoint is found in Rabbi Dr. Tendler's book "Pardes Rimonim," on page 9/10,https://books.google.com/books?id=5uF66eUhokkC&lpg=PP1&pg=PA9#v=onepage&q&f=false

Answer (score 5):

In the [Artscroll Schottenstein](http://www.artscroll.com/Details.aspx?itemNo=9780899067124) edition of Niddah, I found one diagram of the halachic anatomy as understood by Rashi, in footnote 5 on page 17b1 (mouseover to view):

> [image: "Normal route of blood flow through female reproductive system"]

See the rest of the notes there for context and explanation.

As it happens, this chapter was elucidated by one of my high school rabbeim, R' Moshe Zev Einhorn.

Answer (score 1):

"Talmud seems to have understood it"
It understood/spoke of it in a more spiritual way connecting organs in a cause/effect way, I guess it was very similar to the way depicted by Da Vinci since there was not much change in this subject until after him.    (for example the [Vitruvian Man](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitruvian_Man) is 4 Amos tall and 4 Amos wide, and ~3 Amos is the length until his shoulders, (see [eruvin 48a](https://www.sefaria.org/Eruvin.48a.14?lang=bi), [Toisfos yoma 31a](https://www.sefaria.org/Tosafot_on_Yoma.31a.6.1) and  פניני הלכה "שיעור ד' אמות הוא שיעור המספיק לשכיבת אדם תוך פשיטת ידיו ורגליו")

> [image: "1"]

---

> [image: "2"]

---

“anatomy as we understand it,”.
Is more physical, you can use any modern diagram, I will just give you the names (in halocho with the matching scientific name) as I understand them from [Shulchan aruch harav yorah daiya 183.1](http://chabadlibrary.org/books/adhaz/sh/sh5/4/183/1.htm)

מקור=רחם=חדר.
 =
Uterus=Womb.

וצואר הרחם=פרוזדור=בית הרחם = צואר הרחם.
 =
vagina + vulval vestibule  (meaning from the cervix until the Labium minorum (including))

ופתח הפרוזדור=ראש צואר הרחם.
  =
 Cervix

עליה.
 =
the place from which the Female ejaculant comes = either the bladder or the skene's gland  (The ovaries and the fallopian tubes might also be located near there)

לול.
 =
 the hole through which the ejaculant flows = either the urinary meatus or the hole of the skene's gland

Not from the above source.
בתולים.
 =
hymen

---

"My ideal diagram would account for those disputes.".
Please give some examples of disputes

---

The rest of the page brought in the answer above (see end of footnote 2, where because they do not consider the vulval vestibule as part of the vagina they bring another opinion on what is the לול (that it is a perforation caused by infection between the urethra and the vagina, which might have been common in the times of the talmud))

> [image: 1]

Comment: very interesting   + q.  personally I think that anatomic knowledge evolution is responsible for the discrepancy between our understanding and mishna  הפרוזדור והעליה. Bartolini ducts are not a plausible explanation

Comment: @kouty how about the urethra (whould it not make sense that blood in the bladder can come becouse of the reason . ודם העליה כולו טהור שהוא כמו דם מכה שבמעים או בכבד או בכוליא וכיוצא בהם)?

Comment: there are indeed women with a urethra meatus which is a  bit  inside the  vagin.  a minority

Comment: @kouty why does it need to be inside the vagin, anything in the vulval vestibule is also "inside"?

Comment: @kouty והאבר נכנס לפנים מן הלול בשעת גמר ביאה will also make sense

Comment: @kouty especially if "cat position" (the position Eliyahu hanovi revived the dead)

Comment: I don't know.  I will re-read your post more carefully